# How to request value of only some fields related to issues of a repository on Github from Github API?

Tags: api, github, github-api

When I am using a Github API URL like - https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/issues 
to get issues related information for jquery/jquery repository then the API returns information about issues with all the fields for a particular issue like -

```
"url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/issues/2192",
    "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/issues/2192/labels{/name}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/issues/2192/comments",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery/issues/2192/events",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2192",
```

But I don't want these all fields for a particular issue. I want the API to return only these fields instead of returning all the fields-

```
created_at
closed_at
pull_request
```

I am not using CURL. I am only using the API URL to get JSON data from Github API using a jQuery function -

```
    var issues_data;
    $.getJSON(URL, function(json){
      issues_data= json;                                 
    });
```

$.getJSON(URL, function(json) makes use of the URL as specified above and request information related to issues of jquery/jquery repository. But the returned information contains every field about each issue that makes the result size bigger and makes it a heavy request.

I want the Github API to return only above 3 fields for each issue instead of all the fields.

If anybody can help by providing the format of the URL or a code then it would be good.

Comment: Does not exist through v3 of the API. v4, based on CodeQL, may have it. See https://github.community/t/requesting-partial-responses-from-github-api-selecting-output-response-fields/952/3

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example URL which uses the three query criteria you specified in your question:

```
https://github.com/search?q=created%3A%3E%3D2013-02-01+closed%3A%3C2013-10-01&type=pr
```

This searches for all pull requests (`type=pr`) which were created on or after February 1, 2013 (`created%3A%3E%3D2013-02-01`) and were also closed before October 1, 2013 (`closed%3A%3C2013-10-01`).

Comment: Actually my question was not only about searching. What I said is that I want that Github API only returns information about aforesaid 3 fields instead of returning information about all other fields. e.g. - by using the URL ( https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/irc.jquery.org/issues ), the API is returning information about issues with all the fields like- url, labels_url, comments_url etc. but I want the API to return only these fields for a particular issue/PR - created_at, closed_at and pull_request.

Comment: Can you clean up your original question to make it clearer exactly what you want?

Comment: I have added more clarification in the question details. Please check.

Comment: Hello Gaurav, were you able to find an answer for this? I have a similar situation where I'm searching repositories. I just want the name and url for each result, not all of the other details. Any idea how to specific the particular fields?

Comment: any solution? +1

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a solution built into the GitHub API; I think it does not exist.

I am writing json to a file, then filtering results with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

`jq ".[].desiredField" tmp.json > desiredField.txt
<further processing>..`

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub exposes it's API via GraphQL](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql). I think this is what the OP is asking for.